# Gitlab SAST failed with no visible reason

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm testing the SAST functionnality provided automatically by Gitlab.

My project (java, spring boot, maven) compiles well locally with mvn clean package.

I'm working with a hosted Gitlab and shared runners.

CI wasn't implemented yet.

I chose the generated .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stages:
- test
sast:
  stage: test
include:
- template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
```

And then, the job fails with a message like :

```
$ /analyzer run
[INFO] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:27:54Z] ▶ GitLab Find Security Bugs analyzer v2.28.7
[INFO] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:27:54Z] ▶ Detecting project
[INFO] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:27:54Z] ▶ Found project in /builds/myrepo/myproject
[INFO] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:27:54Z] ▶ Running analyzer
[INFO] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:27:54Z] ▶ Found Mvnw project in /builds/myrepo/myproject directory
[INFO] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:27:54Z] ▶ Found 1 analyzable projects.
[INFO] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:27:54Z] ▶ Building Mvnw project at /builds/myrepo/myproject.
[ERRO] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:29:08Z] ▶ Project couldn't be built: exit status 1
[FATA] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:29:08Z] ▶ exit status 1
```

How can I know what went wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the second to last line of the container:

```
[ERRO] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:29:08Z] ▶ Project couldn't be built: exit status 1
[FATA] [Find Security Bugs] [2021-11-01T16:29:08Z] ▶ exit status 1
```

Assuming that your maven job is building fine locally, and it's building fine in a different maven container, I'd suggest that you configure the logging on the SAST job using the logging levels defined in the documentation, and gather some additional information: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#logging-level

Comment: Thanks to you, I was able to see that a dependancy from Jasper couldn't be resolved. Now I can work on it. Thanks.